# standardSQL: Can't extract DAY from timestamp

Tags: timestamp, google-bigquery

I can't extract days from the timestamp variable called *repository.created_at* with `EXTRACT()` function.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT repository.created_at AS fechas,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE repository.created_at)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested`
LIMIT 100
```

How solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  repository.created_at AS fechas,
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y/%m/%d %X %z', repository.created_at))
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested`
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The field `repository.created_at` is of type STRING. You need to parse it as a date before extracting the day.

This should work:

```
SELECT repository.created_at AS fechas,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM PARSE_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", 
SUBSTR(repository.created_at, 0, 10)))
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested`
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wouter. I try to migrate all my legacy SQL to standard SQL code, and I don't how to deal with it.

Comment: actually, this solution gives wrong result as it does not account for time zone!